# problem creating alias in script bash_aliases as root user

Tags: bash, aliases

This is my simplified `/home/user/bash_aliases` script, called from `/home/user/bashrc`. It works well, the 'sql' alias is available after execution (i.e., opening a new terminal):

```
set -x
echo 'This is my bash_aliases'
alias sql='cd /home/user/sw_develop/C/sqlite'
echo 'done'
```

Doing the same as root user does not work (calling `/root/bash_aliases` from `/root/bashrc`). No alias is created, but the script is executed, see output:

```
++echo 'This is my bash_aliases'
This is my bash_aliases
++ alias 'sql=cd /home/user/sw_develop/C/sqlite'
++ echo done
done
```

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason why it it doesn't work myself: The root's bashrc is different to my bashrc. No more help needed. Thanks Sarah